# Word for describing a book with its sheets separated

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What is a suitable word for describing a book that its sheets are separated from each other and its binding?

The intended sentence is something like : *He was holding a portion of my XXXXX copy of Jackson's textbook*.

Edit after Chris's answer:

I want to imply that the book is unbinded as a result of being used and studied too much.

(You are welcome to modify other parts of the above sentence too, to make it more clear.)

Comment: You mean that pages were ripped out of the book?

Comment: @KristinaLopez Yes! Exactly.

Comment: *Manuscript* means something very similar. [Wikipedia: Manuscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manuscript)

Comment: He was holding a handful of pages ripped from my copy of Jackson's textbook.  Or to imply falling apart because of use:  He was holding a handful of pages that had fallen out of my well-used copy of Jackson's textbook.

Comment: He was holding a portion of my **ragged** copy of Jackson's textbook?

Answer (score 8):

Bibliophiles have their own jargon for the various ways a book can be damaged— *foxed*, *warped*, a whole slew of *c-* words from to *chipped* to *cockled* to *crimped*; see [ILAB glossary](https://www.ilab.org/eng/glossary.html) for a few. The technical term for a book that has lost its binding is *[disbound](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disbound)*, which Merriam-Webster defines as simply

> no longer having a binding (*a disbound pamphlet*)

But there isn't, so far as I know, an English idiom that refers to a book becoming disbound due to *overuse*. For whatever reason, the English noticed wear and tear on the *pages* of the book rather than its spine, and so a book that is worn out from overuse is very often described as *tattered* and/or *dog-eared*, and perhaps *frayed* (especially of cloth bookcovers). Per MW again:

> **[tattered](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tattered)** - 2:  torn into shreds:  ragged (*a tattered flag*)
>   3a:  broken down :  dilapidated (*decaying houses along tattered paved streets — P. B. Martin*)
>   b:  being in a shattered condition (*led their tattered party to victory*)
>
> **[dog-eared](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dog-eared)** -  1: having dog-ears (*a dog–eared book*)
>   2:  shabby, timeworn (*a dog–eared resort* *dog–eared myths*)

(a *dog-ear* is a folded-down corner of a page, used to hold a place)
[image: Photo of a dog-eared book from Wikimedia Commons, GFDL by Derbeth]

> 3 **[fray](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frayed)** (intransitive) - 1: to wear out or into shreds
>   2:  to show signs of strain

Comment: _Tattered_ is good, but my intuition says it’s more likely to be used about cloth(es) than books. For books, I would think _battered_ was more commonly used.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I semi-agree; I'd think of a "battered book" having "tattered pages."

Answer (score 3):

If the pages have become *detached* from the book cover you could say

> He was holding the detached pages...

However, the word  *pages* alone is a sufficient and the phrase *dilapidated copy* explains why the pages are separate.

> He was holding the pages of my dilapidated copy of Jackson's textbook

Google Books offer this example:

> In our auction of June 2002 we offered [a dilapidated copy of](http://www.compalcomics.com/marketreport/spring2007.htm) *Our Wullie's* first book of 1941. The spine and part of the front and back cover were worn away...

Answer (score 2):

The word is **unbound**, as in *an **unbound** book*.  However, this implies a book that was never bound.  You might also try **unbinded** to refer to a book that was once bound.  I haven't found much usage for the second term, but I think it would be easily understood.  If you want a more commonly used word, try **disassembled**.

Comment: I want to imply that the books is unbinded as a result of being studied too much.

Answer (score 2):

I think we'd have to go with a cobbled-together phrase to get the meaning across that pages are missing such as:

> *"He was holding a ripped-out portion of my copy of Jackson's textbook."*
>
> *"He was holding a disassembled section of my copy of Jackson's textbook."*
>
> *"He was holding a fistful of pages from my now page-missing copy of Jackson's textbook."*
>
> *"He was holding an amputated portion of my now incomplete copy of Jackson's textbook."*

Answer (score 2):

> He was holding a handful of pages **from / that belonged to** my copy of Jackson's textbook, which had **fallen apart.**

Answer (score 1):

How about **stack of loosened pages of**, or simply **loosened pages of**, it's not a single word but otherwise it fits and can be used in varied registers.

Modified according to @Mari-Lou 's more refined suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

He was holding a [sheaf](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sheaf) of pages, torn from my copy of XXX book.

Comment: Can a sheaf be loose ?, No, it seems.

Comment: @IshanYadav In this case it is bound by the hand. Spread it about on the floor and it's no longer a sheaf.

Answer (score 0):

> He was holding a ragged sheaf of pages — at least several chapters — from the unbound remnants of my copy of Jackson’s textbook.

Answer (score 0):

The adjective *loose-leaf* describes books (especially textbooks) that are sold without binding. I know that's not quite what you want, but perhaps another adjective could help.