# What would be a word or phrase for " missing parts of books or manuscripts"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

> I was reading a Sanskrit manuscript and realized that pages 12 to 19 were missing...

I would simply call those pages as "missing pages", however, is there a word or phrase for such missing parts?

Comment: lacuna - (Printing, Lithography & Bookbinding) a gap or space, esp in a book or manuscript.
(Thank TFD....)

Comment: Sounds like what was asked in this question... http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211966/word-for-describing-a-book-with-its-sheets-separated/211982#211982

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are properly referred to as *lacunae* (singular *lacuna*):

> : a gap or blank space in something : a missing part <*She found a **lacuna** in the historical record.*>

([Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lacuna))

Comment: +1 @Matt Gutting - you got it! Good answer, great word.