# What is the correct term for paper that has become wet and deformed as it dried out?

Tags: single-word-requests

If a paper is submerged in water for some time then left to dry, most often the paper will be deformed. It won't be as flat as it was originally, but wavy (and not wrinkled).

This is most apparent in water damaged books:

[image: A water damaged book]

**Q:** What is the correct terminology for this type of deformation?

Comment: Tangentially related: *[Word for describing a book with its sheets separated](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/211966)*.

Comment: I usually just call it *water damaged*.

Comment: I just came to Martha's Vineyard (Massachusetts, US) and it's so humid here, I have books that did this just sitting on the table. Never got near water, just sucked the moisture right out the air. Now I know what to call this.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Cockled. That is the paper conservator's technical term for wavy or rippled paper. See e.g. [Laura Schell paper conservator](http://www.paperconservationwny.com/treatments.htm):

> **Cockling**
>   Warped and wavy (cockled) paper may be restored to a planar condition by controlled humidification and flattening.

Comment: Interesting! I would have gone with the pedestrian 'warped'. +1

Comment: New one for me too. Very neat word!

Comment: To "cockle" as in to deform so that it takes on the appearance of a cockle (shellfish.) Professionals think up all the best terms. I would have gone for "warped" as well. In my own profession, I recently learned two new terms describing maldistribution of heat on furnace tubes: giraffe necking and tiger tailing (both taken from the appearance of the tubes.)

Comment: It's interesting how close this is to "crinkled", which is not only the word I more often hear to describe this paper, but is also the sound that dry, previously-wet paper makes when handled.

Comment: Upvoted *cockled*, but `+1` for *crinkled* too. That's the word that most people would understand.

Comment: @CarlSmith To my ear, *crinkled* implies actual creasing, not just wavy deformation.

Comment: If it were actually creased, I'd probably say *wrinkled*, but yeah, good point.

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in some [comments](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268765/what-is-the-correct-term-for-paper-that-has-become-wet-and-deformed-as-it-dried/268923#comment592609_268767),

**Warped** - is the more general laymen term, but not quite as specific as [Cockled](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/268767/60910) (*which I had not heard before*)

> Become or cause to become bent or twisted out of shape, typically as a result of the effects of heat or dampness[<sup>[1]</sup>](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/warp)

Comment: *Warped* paints the wrong picture in my mind. It implies a single, large bend as opposed to a wavy, scalloped pattern - a single undulation instead of many. I like cockled and will search desperately for a chance to use it.